# InvalidQueryParameterValue : Status: 400 (Value for one of the query parameters specified in the request URI is invalid.)

Tags: .net, azure-functions, azure-storage

I am implementing an Azure Function with .net6 that connect to an Azure Storage account to upload and delete some files.
This is my Azure Function :

```
    [FunctionName("StoragePostFunction")]
    public static async Task<IActionResult> Post(
        [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req, ILogger log)
    {
        string connection = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("AzureWebJobsStorage");
        string containerName = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ContainerName");
        Stream myBlob = new MemoryStream();
        var file = req.Form.Files["File"];
        myBlob = file.OpenReadStream();
        var blobClient = new BlobContainerClient(connection, containerName);
        var blob = blobClient.GetBlobClient(file.FileName);
        await blob.UploadAsync(myBlob);
        return new OkObjectResult("file uploaded successfylly");
    }
```

**when I test it locally with Postman `http://localhost:7211/api/StoragePostFunction`, it works fine. But when I publish this Azure Function and test it with postman it gives me this**

```
error Status: 400 (Value for one of the query parameters specified in the request URI is invalid.)
ErrorCode: InvalidQueryParameterValue
```

[image]

Can anyone help me please ?

Comment: What's the value for your `AzureWebJobsStorage` and `ContainerName` environment variables?

Comment: AzureWebJobsStorage contain the connection string of the azure storage and ContainerName contains the name of the container that I created

Comment: @Hiba Can you change the name of your connection string other than `AzureWebJobsStorage` as in function app there will be one field with the same name like [this](https://i.imgur.com/zdaOEvs.png) which is responsible for storing all the functions code

Comment: @Hiba I am able to upload the file using the same code without any modification except the connection string, [output](https://i.imgur.com/Zbu5JHP.png)

Comment: @IkhtesamAfrin that's weird because I still have the same issue !

Comment: @Hiba Have you added the environment field values in Configuration post deployment

Comment: Ah now it works when I added the environment fields, thanks for helping ! you can put your comment as an answer and I will accept it @IkhtesamAfrin

Comment: did you copy the function URL from azure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Converting my comments into answer to help the community***

After publishing the code to function app, you need to add the environment variable in ***App settings*** of ***Environment Variables*** Blade as shown below.

[image]

After adding the environment variables, I am able to get the output.

[image]

***Please note***, local.settings file doesn't get deployed while publishing to function app, so you need to add the environment variables in App settings.